# Execute shell command line in java to get a variable

Tags: spring, shell, jakarta-ee

i'm trying to get the version variable and display my current app version in my user interface

the commande line looks like this :

> ls -l
>
> total 24
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 username 33 Sep 15  2016 current ->
>   /dir1/dir2/dir3/current-app-version

i would like to know how to get that "current" variable

can anyone explain for me and guide me

it's my first time doing something like this
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Java open the file `/dir1/dir2/dir3/current-app-version` and read the content, it will show the current version if its present in the file `current-app-version`

else if the app version is the file name, then from java access the file in dir3 and use that in java code.

Answer (score 0):

That "current" is no variable. It is just a symbolic link, like a link to an Applikation in Windows.

Is there any content in that file /dir1/dir2/dir3/current-app-version?
Try:

```
cat /dir1/dir2/dir3/current-app-version
```

Comment: yes there is 3 files , and yes current is just a symbolic link as u said , it represents the current version of the app when u clic on it, it will have the current version as a file name and u will find those  3 files in it, and i just wanted to know how can i get that current version in my java code to display it in my front interface